# Extracting the outline (or bookmarks) from PDF files using Java

Tags: java, pdf, text, extract

I'm using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to extract the outline (bookmarks) information from PDF files, that's even explained in the same site.

However, I've had problems not extracting but generating the qualified urls (`foo.pdf#page=22777&zoom=2,2,777`) to open the PDF in those bookmarks. Sometimes `PDFBox` is not able to find the page in which the bookmark is placed (i.e. the page number, left coordinate or top coordinate are wrong.)

Anyone knows a PDF library capable to do this (preferably in Java)? Thanks.

Best regards,

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText (http://itextpdf.com) might work for you.

I've used it mostly to create PDFs (not so much with parsing already exitingones), but the library is good, and does have objects related to outlines and bookmarks.

Comment: Yeah iText is working like a charm, I'm extracting pages correctly using it! They even provide an example in their toolbox (http://bit.ly/cvf5iT).

Comment: Fantastic. Glad it was able to help.